# Stop server on digitalocean ubuntu .net with gitlab-ci

Tags: .net, gitlab, gitlab-ci, digital-ocean

I`m using gitlab-ci for deploying .net application on Digitalocean. With gitlab runner I build project on Gitlab, with "dotnet build", with the next step I need to stop somehow the server on Digitalocean to run rsync for the new version.

How can I stop .net if it not inside docker container.

My step looks like:

```
-
    - "dotnet build"
    - cd ..
    - ssh $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP '
    - /home/myproject
    // here needs step for stoping
    - rsync -az ./server/bin/ $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP:/home/myproject
    # Non interactive ssh gracefully reloads server
    - ssh $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP '.
      /etc/profile;
      systemctl restart nginx;'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systemd files will allow to manage a process by providing `start, stop, restart, and log` functionalities once you create a process of work called a `unit`.

Into `systemd` directory I've created new service `sudo nano my.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My application

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/my-directory
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/my-directory/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish/MyApplication.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=movie
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In my case, as ConectionString was null, the problem was with directory from where I call `dotnet`. If you have this problem change the next two lines

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/my-directory/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/publish/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet MyApplication.dll
```

And inside `gitlab-ci`

```
-
    - "dotnet build"
    - cd ..
    - ssh $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP '
    - /home/myproject
    # stop step
    - ssh $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP '.
      /etc/profile;
      systemctl stop my.service;'
    - rsync -az ./server/bin/ $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP:/home/myproject
    # Non interactive ssh gracefully reloads server
    - ssh $SERVER_USER@$PROD_SERVER_IP '.
      /etc/profile;
      systemctl start my.service;
      systemctl restart nginx;'
```